# Calculated field in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React / Redux, but that's what I plan to use for an upcoming project. Is there an equivelant of KnockoutJs's ComputedObservable? I plan to have an outer component with a master array, and then multiple subcomponents each responsible for displaying a subset of the items in the parent component's array based on some criteria. Imagine:

[{
 id:1,
 color: 'blue'
},
{
 id:2,
 color: 'blue'
},
{
 id:3,
 color: 'green'
}]

(say, blue colors displayed in the first component instance, green colors displayed in the second component instance). I want to make sure that the dependency between them is clear, so that if the value for an item changes in the parent array, the child component that happens to be displaying that item will rerender.

I imagine that the parent component will pass the master array into each child component via props, and then each child component will be responsible for deciding which subset to display, but I still am not sure about how it will know when to rerender. (Imagine I update a 'blue' to be 'green')

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about when to re-render. React will do the update for you.

I'll do this in your case:

**Sub component**

```
const Item = props => (
  <div style={{ color: props.color }}>
    {props.color}
  </div>
)
```

**Render() of parent component**

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.data.map(d => <Item key={d.id} color={d.color} />)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now when you call `setState()` (or if the `data` is come from Redux and you dispatch an action to update the data), React will re-render the parent and all the sub components.

You can see the working example here: https://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/oebLjZ?editors=0010

Comment: That's really helpful. Thank you for the example. Some of the syntax in UpdateColor is unfamiliar to me so I'll spend some time reviewing it. One last question, if you have time: Are you able to tweak it so that blue elements show in one div, and green elements show in another?

Comment: It depends on your use case. If the elements of same color are always wrapped in a same `div`, I'll change the structure of the data

Comment: For example: `{ blue: [{ id: 1, xxx: 'ooo' }, { id: 2, xxx: 'oooo' }], green: [{ id: 3, xxx: 'zzz' }] }`

Comment: That's interesting. I was on the fence about storing the data that way for two reasons: 1) I plan to move items frequently between blue and green (not a big deal but a simpler operation just updating one field), and 2) I'm still going to be interested in stats on the entire list (eg, how many total items are there? again, possible to sum both array, but easier if they're all still in one array). Maybe I'm not thinking about this the right way.

Comment: To be a bit more specific, I'm thinking about a to-do list-like web app, where the user could create multiple list categories (essentially separate lists). The user should eventually be able to move items from one list (category) to another. If I have a work and a home list, it's certainly interesting to know how many items are in each list, but it's also interesting to know about the entire "master" list. I guess it may just be the case that either way, I'll have tradeoffs in terms of moving items between lists vs aggregating multiple lists.

Comment: You can check this: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

Comment: I think you don't always need to fully normalize the data. For a simple scenario arrays will work. I wrote another example here: 
https://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/Bdjzbe?editors=0010

Comment: Note that I didn't optimize it. The complexity of the above example is O(n * m). To optimize you can preprocess `todos` and group them by categories